# How to wait execute method in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have one issue I wrote code like 
`private class SomeClass extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckOutActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.wait));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
//some code
}
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
}`

I execute class like this

`new SomeClass().execute();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

  Now My question is when .execute() start the code like not wait it means the Toast like execute before completion of SomeClass().execute(); Is there any Property for waiting this .execute() method.

**EDIT:** I assign some values to globle variable and after this execution I just want to compare this value. So I just put Toast message.

Comment: is your issue  to show the Toast when the asynctask finish?

Comment: yes i want to toast after execution

Comment: then show it inside  onPostExecute

Comment: @blackbelt I Know this but i want to wait execution and after that i just execute my code line

Comment: Thanks for negative my question. Don't know who is he/she. If you know my problem than just help me

Comment: you should look at the delegate pattern

Comment: You don't ever do that.  The entire point of an AsyncTask is the onPostExecute method.  That's where the logic is supposed to go for anything that occurs when the task is finished.  If you want to wait, then you shouldn't use an AsyncTask at all, you should just have your code there.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Thanks!! Now I got Solution Completely..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `Toast` logic into `onPostExecute()` if you want it to display after the work is complete.

Comment: thanks, I know this solution.actually I want to know how to wait this process

Comment: if you will "block wait" for asynctask is completed there will be no use for it

Comment: what do you meant by **how to wait** ?? Please elaborate this....

Comment: @BhavinChauhan: "I know this solution" -- then please implement it. "actually I want to know how to wait this process" -- the complete and entire point of an `AsyncTask` is to do work in a background thread without blocking the main application thread. Hence, talented programmers use `onPostExecute()` for work to be done on the main application thread after the background work has completed.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for clearing my Async Task...

Answer (score 0):

Calling `get()` on the async task will essentially make it no longer asynchronous and will block the main thread.

From the android docs

`Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.`

**NOTE** this isn't really a good idea to do since you should never block the main thread.

Usage:

```
new SomeClass().execute().get();
```

Comment: thanks.. How it write with code line??

Comment: than why you use `AsyncTask` at all? only to avoid NetworkOnMTE? using `get()` is like shooting at own foot ... instead of `new SomeClass().execute().get()` you can just put `doInBackground` code here ...